# How can I see websockets actor in activator ui inspector?

Tags: playframework

I'm trying to inspect my application's websockets actors in activator ui inspector. I'm using play 2.3.1. The inspector shows me play requests, some other actors but not the actors created to work with the websockets.

One thing that I noticed is that the websocket actor is in the system namespace. The inspector show actors in the user namespace. How can I inspect them? Is it possible? Is there any other recommended monitoring alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've opened an issue in [play](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/3872) and [activator](https://github.com/typesafehub/activator/issues/878) projects. They pointed me a solution by configuration.

Using the [sbt-echo](https://github.com/typesafehub/sbt-echo) configurations I've managed to see my websocket handlers actors.

1. In build.sbt add `import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtEcho._`
2. Add `EchoKeys.traceable in Echo += "/system/websockets*" -> true`
3. Start the ***activator ui*** and go to ***inspect*** panel

And that's it! All websockets handlers and their children will be visible!